# Grep for double forward slash and asterisk in file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am currently work with large number of JCL files (mainframe job file).
I want to grep all the comment line start with //*space in each file then write to another file.

```
//SYSDBOUT DD  SYSOUT=I
//*----------------------------------------------------------
//*       STEP1 <---the line I want to grep
//*----------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is the grep statement only work with double forward slash.

```
egrep '^//'
```

Anyone has any solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the asterisk (`*`):

```
$  grep '^//\* ' *.jcl
```

Comment: @TùngNguyễn, `*` is a metacharacter just like `^` metacharacter.. so, to turn off that special meaning(because you want to literally match `*` here), you have use ``\`` character before `*`.. that is called escaping